# How can I order by a specific condition in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

To list all the shops in my database, I have the query

```
@shops = Shop.includes(:opening_times)
             .references(:opening_times)
             .limit(paging)
             .offset(@offset)
```

If I want to get only the shops that are open now, I can add

```
.where("opening_times.day =?", today) #Open today
.where("opening_times.opens <= ?", @now)  #Opening time is before now
.where("(opening_times.opens+opening_times.open_for) > ?", @now)  #Closing time is after now
.order("opening_times.opens+opening_times.open_for") #Order by earliest opening time
```

But what I need is to list *all* the shops, with the ones that are currently open at the top. Is there any way to sort the list by whether or not they meet the conditions for being currently open?

This is using postgres.

Comment: What happens if you put your condition in the `order by` clause instead? It should still work, I believe.

Comment: @Teeg You mean like `.order("opening_times.day =?", today)`? That gives me _ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input_.

Comment: Ok, some DBMSes let you do this, obviously postgres doesn't. Its usually good to post which database you're using as some allow certain things, while others don't. I'll give this some thought and get back if I can...